# How to select a subset from a dataframe or an array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to select columns from first to ninth and eleventh in numpy array.
Something like union `X[:, 1:10]` and `X[:, 11]`
I tried `X[:, [1:10, 1]]`,  but there was an error

P.S. I've found the solution: `np.concatenate((X[:, 1:10], X[:,[11]]), axis=1)`
But I think it's too long

Comment: I think you are looking for something like `X[X.columns[np.r_[1:10, 11]]]`

Comment: another variation would be `X.iloc[:, np.r_[1:10, 11]]`